# Want to trigger click event function from protovis(Javascript Graph Library)

Tags: javascript, protovis

By using graph library protovis i had brought a bar graph.

**Question:** *Once i click on a bar. I want to get or display details of that bar in a div[image]*

Refer Documentation of protovis at `http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/bar.html`

Help me i want to access the bar in javascript or jquery to fetch details of particular bar

Answer (score -3, accepted):

My Final solution is Dont use protovis since Protovis wont support ie compactability. For Checking this test link in ie7 http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/bar.html

**I Warn Protovis Team to test the compactability in all browser before releasing it.**

IE7 Shows object Error While using protovis and graph is not displayed

Comment: Protovis uses SVG to render the graphs. Older versions of IE does not render SVG. This is not Protovis' fault.

Comment: A open source should be render to use in all browsers. so this is a pitfall in protovis. i suggest its not good library to render graph.

Comment: Check this post out there is a lit to make protovis work with IE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645088/is-protovis-supposed-to-work-on-ie-7-8-and-9-like-raphaeljs-does/6399312#6399312

Comment: Naturally the plugin wont supports with ie older versions[ie6, ie7]. Its not good to use protovis. then ur wish...