# Is Protovis supposed to work on IE 7, 8, and 9 like RaphaelJS does?

Tags: raphael, protovis

I thought [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) might work on IE 7 and 8, or at least on IE 9... but to my surprise, I tried it on all 3 and it doesn't work on any (for those example pages... is it a temporary JS bug?)... is it supposed to work on IE at all, like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) does?  (even on IE 6, amazing...)

I can't find any list of supported browsers on the Protovis website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protovis requires SVG and IE 6 - 8 do not support SVG.  IE 9 does support SVG, so Protovis should work fine on IE 9.

In order to work on IE 6-8 it is necessary for the user to install ChromeFrame, which will install the Chrome rendering ending into IE.

Answer (score 1):

My google tells me you're not alone: http://code.google.com/p/protovis-js/issues/detail?id=15. From here: http://code.google.com/p/protovis-js/updates/list